# Firebase error: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently having an error and I don't know why. The error only happens when I reload a products page then I get the error in the img below. The page still loads all the products so I don't know what is happening. I think it has to do with props.Cat which just contains a string with the category name passed down from my app.jsx

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { firestore } from "../../../FireBase/FireBase";
import Button from "../../Elements/Button/Button";
import "./Products2.scss";

const Product = (props) => {
  const [ProductList, setProductList] = useState([]);
  const [cartList, setCart] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCart = async () => {
      const doc = await firestore.collection("Users").doc(props.id).get();
      const data = doc.data();
      if (data === []) {
        setCart(null);
      } else {
        setCart(data.cart);
      }
    };

    fetchCart();
  }, [props]);

  const getProduct = async () => {
    if (props.Cat) {
      try {
        var list = [];
        var snapshot = await firestore.collection(props.Cat).get();
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push(doc.data());
        });
        setProductList([...list]);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    else{
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProduct();
  },);

  const addCart = async (name, img, price) => {
    try {
      var quanChangeAt = null;
      var item = {
        id: name,
        Name: name,
        Img: img,
        Quan: 1,
        price: price,
      };
      if (cartList === null) {
        alert("Please Login first");
        return;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
        if (cartList[i].Name === item.Name) {
          quanChangeAt = i;
        }
      }
      if (quanChangeAt !== null) {
        item.Quan = cartList[quanChangeAt].Quan + 1;
        cartList[quanChangeAt] = item;
        await firestore.collection("Users").doc(props.id).update({
          cart: cartList,
        });
      } else {
        cartList.push(item);
        await firestore.collection("Users").doc(props.id).update({
          cart: cartList,
        });
      }
      alert(name + " added to cart succefully");
      console.log("added cart", cartList);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  if (!ProductList) {
    // You can render a placeholder if you like during the load, or just return null to render nothing.
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="ProductLayout">
      <h1>{props.Cat}</h1>
      <div className="products">
        {ProductList.map((listItem) => (
          <div className="item" key={listItem.Name}>
            <h2>{listItem.Name}</h2>
            <img src={listItem.img} alt={listItem.Name} />
            <h5>Description</h5>
            <p>{listItem.Description}</p>
            <br />
            <h5>Envirmental Benifit</h5>
            <p>{listItem.EvntBenefit}</p>
            <br />
            <h5>Price</h5>
            <p>$ {listItem.price}</p>
            <Button
              onClick={() =>
                addCart(listItem.Name, listItem.img, listItem.price)
              }
            >
              Add to cart
            </Button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like `props.id` is not set.  The last function of yours to be called before the crash was `fetchCart()`.

You can easily verify this by adding `` console.log(`##### props.id: ${props.id}`) `` to the first line of `fetchCart()`.  The result will probably print `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: You are correct. When added that statement the id came out null then after it loaded came out with the right id. First I wanted to ask how you read that stack trace to find where the crash is? Secondly, how do you think I could fix this and make the program wait until the id isn't null?

Comment: I found a solution and edited the question to have the solution but I would still like to know how you read that error to find where it was occurring.

Comment: In Javascript, the stack trace prints the specific error causing function at the top, and each layer down is the function that called the one above it.  Looking at yours, the first few lines are system functions, and the 5th function is yours, `fetchCart`.  As far as knowing it was null, the error message `CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path` implies that path is empty, so either you passed `null` or a literal empty  string (that one seemed less likely)